# sorting out the latest filedate in a VIEW in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to make a view out of three tables in my database. 
[image: How it looks]

I'm trying to only show the latest filetime that I have. As you can see I have a vehicle that shows two different values depending on the filetime (I have marked that area with a red square).

I would only like to show the latest filetime. How do i do that? I have tried with group on and using max. But it doesn't work. Here is my current code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT MAX(db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts.ReadOutID) AS ReadOutID,
          db_ddladmin.Data_Values.Identifier, db_ddladmin.Data_Values.ECU, 
          MAX(db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts.FileTime) AS FILETIME,
          MAX(db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts.FileName) AS FN,
          db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles.Name, db_ddladmin.Data_Values.Value
FROM db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts
  INNER JOIN db_ddladmin.Data_Values
      ON db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts.ReadOutID = db_ddladmin.Data_Values.ReadOutID
  INNER JOIN db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles
      ON db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts.VehicleID = db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles.ID
GROUP BY db_ddladmin.Data_Values.Identifier, db_ddladmin.Data_Values.ECU,
         db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles.Name, db_ddladmin.Data_Values.Value
ORDER BY MAX(db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles.Name)
```

EDIT: The values are from readouts from the vehicle. Why i need the latest filetime is because i want the latest readout. ReadOutID is a number which is given when a readout is made. The higher the number the later the readout is. FN is Filename and it consists the milage and filetime when the readout was made.

Comment: Did you mark the rows you want to see in result?

Comment: yes! I would like to have the latest readoutID, latest filetime and latest name

Comment: The TOP(100) PERCENT and order by is redundant in a view, since Views, Like tables, are un ordered sets in any relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ReadOutID,
        Identifier, 
        ECU, 
        FileTime, 
        FileName, 
        Name, 
        [Value] 
FROM (
    SELECT  dr.ReadOutID, 
            dv.Identifier, 
            dv.ECU, 
            dr.FileTime, 
            dr.FileName, 
            dve.Name, 
            dv.[Value],
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dve.Name ORDER BY dr.FileTime DESC) as drnk
    FROM db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts dr 
    INNER JOIN db_ddladmin.Data_Values dv
        ON dr.ReadOutID = dv.ReadOutID 
    INNER JOIN db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles dve
        ON dr.VehicleID = dve.ID
    ) as rv
WHERE drnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you don't need aggregation.  Just use `ROW_NUMBER()` and select the most recent for each vehicle:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT r.ReadOutID, v.Identifier, v.ECU, r.FileTime, r.FileName, ve.Name, v.Value
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ve.id ORDER BY r.FileTime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts r INNER JOIN
           db_ddladmin.Data_Values v
           ON r.ReadOutID = v.ReadOutID INNER JOIN
           db_ddladmin.Data_Vehicles ve
           ON r.VehicleID = ve.ID
    ) rv
WHERE seqnum =  1;
```

Also, notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Should i write this code in the design mode in the View or as a new query? I think there is a "(" missing somewhere but i can't seem to find it.
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('."

Comment: @AdnanHossain add `,` after `v.Value`

Comment: Thank you @gofr1. I tried this solution and i only get 326 row which can't be right since i have around 150000 rows normally. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @AdnanHossain query provided by Gordon will show only recent for each vehicle id. So 1 per vehicle. That's why there are only 326 in result. Try `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VehicleID) FROM db_ddladmin.Data_Readouts)` what results wil this query show?

Comment: It shows 327 @gofr1
The thing is that these values are from different readouts made from vehicles. So let's say i got a readout that was made 20160101 and a readout 20160201. Then i would only like to show the values from the readout from 20160201 since i want the latest values on the specific vehicle

Comment: @AdnanHossain there was Vehicles in your question, if you need RedadOut's change this part: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.ReadOutID ORDER BY r.FileTime DESC) `

Comment: still don't work and i think i know why. It only shows readoutID once. Let's say we have AKKA which is a vehicle. The readout that was made 20160201 have the readoutID 200. And AKKA consists of 100 values and all those values has readoutID 200. Do you understand what i mean? @gofr1

Comment: @AdnanHossain yes, I understand. Your example from last comment - illustrates situation pretty well. Please, edit your question: add what output you are getting now for some vehicle, and what output you desire.

Comment: @gofr1, will do that! the problem is that im very close to getting it right by having aggregate functions. But there are some lines where it goes wrong and it shows both the latest readout and a older readout. If you look at the picture i posted you can see that AKKA has EBS7 where the is a value from a readout made 20160405 and a different value from a readout 20160415. I can't find the error. Thank you very much for your time. Really appriciate it

Comment: @AdnanHossain My pleasure! You can try `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ve.Name ORDER BY r.FileTime DESC) as seqnum`

Comment: @gofr1 It worked! I owe you one. You can write it as an answer so i can mark it as the right solution. Thank you!

Comment: @AdnanHossain yeah! Posted. :) once again, my pleasure to help!